# Allow IPs overriding deny rule

Tags: nginx

If one blocks IPs using a deny rule, e.g.

```
deny 123.124.2.0/24;
```

Is it possible to then allow certain IPs in that range/CIDR block?

I would like to block all AWS (Amazon) IPs, but there are a small number of IPs I need to allow from the AWS ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Nginx manual http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html

> The rules are checked in sequence until the first match is found.

So placing your allow/deny rules in the correct order will allow you to exclude specific IP-address from the policy of a specific subnet.

```
allow 123.124.2.13;
deny  123.124.2.0/24;
```

has the effect: all IP's from that subnet except 123.124.2.13 are denied.